# Sharepoint Folder

Tags: folder

How do i give access to someone outside my network to a sharepoint folder, without giving them access to anything else on the site?  I would like them to have access to upload and manage files to that folder.

thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Which is your SharePoint version.

Comment: Which kind of authantication do you have in SharePoint (Windows integrated, Forms-based, Claims Based with external claims provider)? If it is based on Active Directory, does the external co-worker have an account in AD? Does he have access to the SharePoint server at the network level (I mean ports opened, authentication on firewall etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to permissions for that folder, select the option to stop inheriting permissions from it's parent, then give the user the desired level of permissions for that folder (probably Contribute).